# $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ uniformly converge to $0$ or not

Tags: real-analysis

I am learning uniformly convergence of function, I found that $x^{n+1}/n+1$  uniformly converge to $0$ in my note and it did not specify the domain. And I am thinking,

For $ x>1$,

$\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \gt \frac{x}{n+1} $,

then for any $\epsilon$,
$\frac{x}{n+1}\lt \epsilon$  iff $n\gt \frac{x}{\epsilon} -1$

Then when x goes to infinity then n goes to infinity too.
It seems that $$\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ does not uniformly converge to zero on any domains contain numbers bigger than or equal to 1. 
And it converges to 0 uniformly on $[0,1)$

Comment: If $x>1$, $\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ does not tend to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sup_{x\in [-1,1]}|\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}|=\frac{1}{n+1}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. So we indeed have uniform convergence in $[-1,1]$. And as you noted there is no convergence (even point wise) to $0$ if $|x|> 1$.